# For loop to threads in JAVA 1.8

Tags: java

I have a list of objects, and size is more than 5000.
I want to loop over 5000 times to perform various file operations.
I am planning use threads instead of forloop or foreach.

need suggestions/way to achive this

Comment: "various file operations" - file operations are usually much slower than the program itself. What is more, they can't be parallelized and you will be bottlenecked by OS and hard drive.

Comment: @Amongalen, yeah, thats the reason, i am  planning for thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use
streamParallel()
In your code with lambda.
It will create a stream parallel to all concurrent threads.
This is made for many objects within a single list.
I also recommend using LinkedList because there is more performance with looping through the objects, as far as I know.

This is what should help you out:

```
public <R> void loopThrough(LinkedList<R> list, Consumer<R> consumer) {
    list.parallelStream().forEach(consumer);
}
```

I hope it will help. If I got anything wrong, just please let me know.

Comment: I believe that LinkedList may be good at deleting and entering new objects in mid-list, but that ArrayList has better performance overall.

Comment: @NomadMaker or just leave it as `List`, then the same method can be applied to either.

Comment: @NomadMaker , intead of parlletlstream, shall we change it our own threads with like, completable feature, i want complete customization, becuase inner operations are heavy and costly